# How can I change what vim does when I (try to) write the buffer?

Tags: rest, vim

If I read a buffer from an external source, there's no filename associated with the current buffer. That's fine, but what if instead of writing it to a file on disk I want to POST it to a webservice instead?

Can I somehow hook into what `:w` does, and, depending on file type, change *how* it writes the buffer?

In this case, it's fairly easy to use a REST API to get the contents of a pesudo-file on our CMS; but now I want a way to send a `PUT` request back to the API instead of trying to write it to disk.

Ideally the solution would hook into the lowest level possible, so that `:up` and `:x` also have the desired effect.

Comment: won't it be better to use another command to post the request. This will be better than changing built-in functions.

Comment: I also think it's better to create a new command to try this. This behavior should not be associated with "writing the file", since you're clearly not trying to write the file.

Comment: @rgoliveira But I want a transparent interface between my muscle memory and the stuff I'm editing. It's of no concern to me that I'm not *technically* writing the file; as far as I and my muscle memory are concerned, `:w` means save, not write.

Comment: @Altreus I understand what you're saying. If you really want to do this, you can create the functions you need to send/receive stuff from that API, and hook it up with BufWriteCmd. Take a look at [autocmd-events](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#autocmd-events).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `BufWriteCmd` autocommand for this. The expectation from the function you call from this command is that it would 'write' (which in your case is making an API call to post it to some service) and then update the `'modified'` flag to indicate that the file has been saved (usually modified would be true at first, but your function would then set it to false in the end when successfully posted to the service)